# Randomly fill a 3D grid according to a probability density function p(x,y,z)

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, random, probability

**How can I fill a 3D grid in the order specified by a given probability density function?**

Using python, I'd like to lay down points in a *random* order, but according to some specified probability distribution over that region, with no repeated points.

Sequentially:

- create a discrete 3D grid
- specify a probability density function for every grid point, pdf(x,y,z)
- lay down a point (x0,y0,z0) whose random location is proportional to the pdf(x,y,z)
- continue adding points (without repeating) until all locations are filled

The desired result is a list of all points (no repeats) of all the points in the grid, in order that they were filled.

Comment: Are you sure they fill in a cubic shape, and it's not just the projection? What does a 2D slice look like?

Comment: Great question, I thought this might come up.  Unless I'm running up into the boundary (3 in this case, which I'm not), even a projection shouldn't distinguish/show x,y or z, which this clearly does.  This is because the pdf only has *radial* dependence.

Comment: So you're basically trying to generate and plot draws from a multivariate gaussian?

Comment: Yes! - well, in this case.  In general I'd like to specify a pdf with arbitrary spatial dependence.

Comment: why did you edit your question to remove your original code and then post it as answer?

Comment: The original code was wrong - no use having bad code floating around.

Comment: If you had correct code, you wouldn't have asked the question. By removing your original code, correcting it, and posting it as your own answer, you are making it more difficult for someone else who finds this question to see what happened. Furthermore, my answer took your original code and adapted it as minimally as possible to solve the problem. Now, my code seems out of context.

Comment: The idea behind editing the question was to make it very concise and very clear - so removing my bad code was part of this.  The history of the question is not important.  I also think think your answer is plenty relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example, using a gaussian pdf (see plot).  This code is easily adapted to any specified pdf:

```
%matplotlib qt 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

#number of points to lay down:
n = 4000;

#create meshgrid:
min, max, L = -5, 5, 91;
[x_grid,y_grid,z_grid] = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(min,max,L),np.linspace(min,max,L),np.linspace(min,max,L))
xi,yi,zi = x_grid.ravel(),y_grid.ravel(),z_grid.ravel()

#create normalized pdf (gaussian here):
pdf = np.exp(-(x_grid**2 + y_grid**2 + z_grid**2));
pdf = pdf/np.sum(pdf);

#obtain indices of randomly selected points, as specified by pdf:
randices = np.random.choice(np.arange(x_grid.ravel().shape[0]), n, replace = False,p = pdf.ravel())

#random positions:
x_rand = xi[randices]
y_rand = yi[randices]
z_rand = zi[randices]

fig = plt.figure();
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d',aspect='equal')
svals = 16;
ax.scatter(x_rand, y_rand, z_rand, s=svals, alpha=.1)
```

[image: scatter plot generated by code]

Answer (score 2):

The below does not implement drawing from a multivariate gaussian:

```
xi_sorted = np.random.choice(x_grid.ravel(),x_grid.ravel().shape, replace=False, p = pdf.ravel())
yi_sorted = np.random.choice(x_grid.ravel(),x_grid.ravel().shape, replace=False, p = pdf.ravel())
zi_sorted = np.random.choice(x_grid.ravel(),x_grid.ravel().shape, replace=False, p = pdf.ravel())
```

That is because `p(x)*p(y)*p(z) != p(x,y,z)` unless the three variables are independent. You can consider something like a [Gibbs sampler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_sampling) to draw from the joint distribution by sequentially drawing from univariate distributions.

In the specific case of the multivariate normal, you can use (full example)

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from math import *

num_points = 4000

sigma = .5;
mean = [0, 0, 0]
cov = [[sigma**2,0,0],[0,sigma**2,0],[0,0,sigma**2]]

x,y,z = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean,cov,num_points).T

svals = 16
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d',aspect='equal')
ax.scatter(x,y,z, s=svals, alpha=.1,cmap=cm.gray)
```

Comment: Thanks for stating my error concisely!  I had thought `p(x)*p(y) = p(x,y)` in the special case of gaussian dist. for some reason.  If you can provide code, that would result in a faster upvote / accept :)

Comment: @anon0909 I updated my answer to contain a full working example.