# Python : Reduce grid according to the values of a function

Tags: python, optimization, grid, integration, precision

I have a regularly spaced grid, of let's say 200*200*200 = 8,000,000 points. I also have a list of values of some function *f* (which takes positive and negative values and which varies a lot over space) on every point of this grid, as follows :

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product

x = np.linspace(0, 200*0.05, 200)
y = np.linspace(0, 200*0.05, 200)
z = np.linspace(0, 200*0.05, 200)
coordinates = np.array(list(product(x, y, z)))
```

and

```
In [1]: print(coordinates, coordinates.shape)
[[  0.           0.           0.        ]
 [  0.           0.           0.05025126]
 [  0.           0.           0.10050251]
 ..., 
 [ 10.          10.           9.89949749]
 [ 10.          10.           9.94974874]
 [ 10.          10.          10.        ]]
(8000000, 3)

In [2]: print(f,"\n",f.shape)
[  2.46143000e-08   3.01043000e-08   3.64817000e-08 ...,   6.79642000e-08
   5.83957000e-08   4.95127000e-08]
(8000000,)

In [3]: print(np.max(f), np.min(f), np.min(np.absolute(f)))
6.21966 -271.035 1.10296e-09
```

---

**How can I get a new grid with less points** (~250,000 points)**, that is very precise in regions of high *f* values, and much less precise in regions of low *f* values ?**

This new grid can be regular, but can also be much more sophisticated, as long as I can still integrate the function over space afterwards.
Thank you in advance for your help !

EDIT : I have just discovered the scipy.interpolate.griddata function which will be very useful if I find someway to make a new grid, even if this grid is not regular. Is there any python library that generates grids ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code, inspired by this [following stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725710/randomly-fill-a-3d-grid-according-to-a-probability-density-function-px-y-z), and defined a probability density out of f :

```
n = 250000
g = 2 #the higher g, the more precise the grid will be in regions of high f, and vice-versa

x = np.linspace(0, 200*0.05, 200)
y = np.linspace(0, 200*0.05, 200)
z = np.linspace(0, 200*0.05, 200)
[x_grid,y_grid,z_grid] = np.meshgrid(x,y,z)
xi,yi,zi = x_grid.ravel(),y_grid.ravel(),z_grid.ravel()

#create normalized pdf
pdf = np.log10(np.absolute(f))
pdf = pdf - pdf.min() + 1
pdf = pdf**g
pdf = pdf/np.sum(pdf)

#obtain indices of randomly selected points, as specified by pdf:
randices = np.random.choice(np.arange(x_grid.size), n, replace = False,p = pdf.ravel())

#random positions:
x_rand = xi[randices]
y_rand = yi[randices]
z_rand = zi[randices]

#coordinates
grid_coord = np.array([x_rand, y_rand, z_rand]).swapaxes(0,1)
```